# Characterizing Dedekind domains that are ring of integers.

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, homological-algebra

I apologise if the following question is naive:

> Is there a ring theoretic (or homological) criteria to detect ring of
> integers among Dedekind domains?
>
> In other words, are there theorems that say "[insert ring theoretic
> adjectives] Dedekind domains are ring of integers"?

This is motivated by the homological characterisation of Dedekind domains. I am wondering if the ring of integers can also be characterised homologically.

Note: I am learning homological algebra and I know elementary number theory only.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One characterization you could give is that a Dedekind domain $R$ is the ring of integers in some number field iff it is finitely generated and torsion-free as an abelian group.  These conditions imply that $R$ has characteristic $0$ and its field of fractions is finite dimensional over $\mathbb{Q}$, i.e. a number field.  Since $R$ is finitely generated as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module it is an integral extension of $\mathbb{Z}$, and since it is a Dedekind domain it is integrally closed in its field of fractions.  So $R$ must be the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in its field of fractions, and thus the ring of integers.